# Disk utilization of Dataproc Worker Node is getting increased day by day

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

We have Dataproc cluster of 1 Master node and 7 worker node.
All the worker nodes has 1 boot disk and 1 local disk of 375 GB (sdb).
The sdb(mounted on /mnt/1) disk utilization of worker nodes 0,1,2,3 has reached above 85% and 5,6,7 also gradually increasing towards 85% .

We have found that files under below directory is taking major part (304G)

/mnt/1/hadoop/dfs/data/current/BP-XXXXXXX-XX.XX.XX.X-XXXXXXXX/current/finalized   .

we have found that it has folder below like

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Jul 24 16:11 ..
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Jul 26 15:20 subdir0
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Aug  8 13:19 subdir1
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Aug 10 08:16 subdir2
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Aug 17 22:16 subdir3
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Aug 23 02:49 subdir4
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Aug 27 20:30 subdir5
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep  2 08:30 subdir6
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep  7 02:21 subdir7
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep 12 18:00 subdir8
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep 16 22:46 subdir9
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep 23 02:45 subdir10
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep 28 22:31 subdir11
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Oct  3 19:15 subdir12
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Oct  8 13:30 subdir13
drwxrwxr-x 17 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Oct 12 15:35 .
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Oct 13 04:46 subdir14
```

---

### cd subdir6

ls -larth
total 688K

```
drwxrwxr-x 34 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Sep  2 08:30 .
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  5 22:35 subdir0
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  5 22:51 subdir1
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  5 23:34 subdir2
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 00:28 subdir4
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 00:50 subdir5
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 01:36 subdir6
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 01:50 subdir7
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 02:21 subdir8
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 02:50 subdir9
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 03:19 subdir10
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 03:38 subdir11
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 04:19 subdir12
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 04:38 subdir13
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 05:20 subdir14
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 05:49 subdir15
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 06:19 subdir16
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 07:20 subdir18
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 08:06 subdir20
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 08:24 subdir21
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 08:50 subdir22
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 09:23 subdir23
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 09:39 subdir24
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 10:05 subdir25
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 10:26 subdir26
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 11:02 subdir27
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 11:36 subdir28
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 12:04 subdir29
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 12:24 subdir30
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep  6 12:53 subdir31
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep 10 16:12 subdir17
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep 12 16:13 subdir3
drwxrwxr-x  2 hdfs hdfs  20K Sep 13 16:13 subdir19
drwxrwxr-x 17 hdfs hdfs 4.0K Oct 12 15:35 ..
```

---

XXXX/current/finalized/subdir6# cd subdir0
XXXXX/current/finalized/subdir6/subdir0# ls -larth
total 726M

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  39K Sep  1 18:35 blk_1074135056_394248.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.8M Sep  1 18:35 blk_1074135056
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  38K Sep  1 18:36 blk_1074135053_394245.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.8M Sep  1 18:36 blk_1074135053
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  40K Sep  1 18:36 blk_1074135055_394247.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 5.0M Sep  1 18:36 blk_1074135055
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  39K Sep  1 18:36 blk_1074135049_394241.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.9M Sep  1 18:36 blk_1074135049
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  45K Sep  1 18:38 blk_1074135057_394249.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 5.6M Sep  1 18:38 blk_1074135057
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  39K Sep  1 18:47 blk_1074135070_394262.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.8M Sep  1 18:47 blk_1074135070
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  24K Sep  1 18:47 blk_1074135097_394289.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 2.9M Sep  1 18:47 blk_1074135097
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  36K Sep  1 18:49 blk_1074135141_394333.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.5M Sep  1 18:49 blk_1074135141
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  23K Sep  1 18:49 blk_1074135142_394334.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 2.9M Sep  1 18:49 blk_1074135142
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  36K Sep  1 18:49 blk_1074135134_394326.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.5M Sep  1 18:49 blk_1074135134
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  38K Sep  1 18:50 blk_1074135071_394263.meta
```

--------------------------- Many many file like that ---------------

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  37K Sep  5 22:23 blk_1074192610_451802.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.6M Sep  5 22:23 blk_1074192610
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  37K Sep  5 22:26 blk_1074192592_451784.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 4.6M Sep  5 22:26 blk_1074192592
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs  44K Sep  5 22:33 blk_1074192633_451825.meta
-rw-rw-r--  1 hdfs hdfs 5.5M Sep  5 22:33 blk_1074192633
```

1. Can we delete those file ?
2. What are purpose of those files ?
3. 

## What are best ways to delete those ?

Thanks a lot for the info. I have ran the command.

```
~# hadoop fs -du -h /
136       /hadoop
0         /tmp
1017.5 G  /user


# hadoop fs -du -h /user/spark/
1012.7 G  /user/spark/eventlog
```

The event log seems to take nearly 1TB

```
:~# hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 2766820474880 (2.52 TB)
Present Capacity: 2539325628659 (2.31 TB)
DFS Remaining: 331457595322 (308.69 GB)
DFS Used: 2207868033337 (2.01 TB)
DFS Used%: 86.95%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0
-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (7):
Name: XXXXXX
Hostname: XXXXXX-w-0.c.XXXXXXXX
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 395260067840 (368.11 GB)
DFS Used: 328729737718 (306.15 GB)
Non DFS Used: 10792138250 (10.05 GB)
DFS Remaining: 34530736445 (32.16 GB)
DFS Used%: 83.17%
DFS Remaining%: 8.74%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 18
Last contact: Wed Oct 14 17:52:46 UTC 2020
Last Block Report: Wed Oct 14 14:32:42 UTC 2020
```

===============
above is trimmed output. Remaining 6 nodes are nearly having the same disk usage.

1. Is the deletion of eventlog is safe ? I mean will it hamper any running job or cluster ?
2. I am ran the below command to find how many files are there and I found it is huge.

   ~# hadoop fs -du -h /user/spark/eventlog|wc -l

   236757

All the files nearly have 5~6MB in size. Is there any command by which I can delete the matching files which are at least 7 days old ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories you listed are used by HDFS, you can run the following commands on the master node to figure out which HDFS files are consuming the space:

```
hdfs dfs -du <dir>
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

You can delete unneeded files with

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r -f -skipTrash <path>
```

See more details in [HDFS commands guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html). There are also some nice [scripts](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-identify-what-is-consuming-space-in-HDFS/ta-p/245500) and [tools](https://github.com/twitter/hdfs-du) that might be useful.

Pay attention to `/user/spark/eventlog` and `/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history`, they usually grow as you run more jobs.

## Increasing HDFS capacity

Before you identify and delete unneeded files, to prevent HDFS running out of space, you can add more worker nodes to the cluster as a mitigation:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters update <cluster> --num-workers=<num>
```

See more details in [scaling Dataproc clusters](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scaling-clusters).

## Spark event logs

If it is caused by Spark event logs or history files, for **live clusters**, consider adding these properties in `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true
spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=1d
spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge=7d
```

then restart Spark history server with

```
sudo systemctl restart spark-history-server.service
```

it will clean up the old files for you. You can change the interval to a smaller value e.g., `10m` if you want it to run more frequently.

For **new clusters**, add these properties

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ... \
  --properties spark:spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true,spark:spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=1d,spark:spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge=7d
```

See this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/monitoring.html#spark-history-server-configuration-options) on the related Spark configs. BTW, you can view Spark job history in [Dataproc web UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways), and after cleaning up some old history files, you should see fewer items.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I have updated my question after running your commands. Can you please have a look and let me what I need to do now.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The idea is let Spark history server clean up for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dagang . It worked . Utl reduced to 10% now.

Comment: Glad to know that. Could you accept the answer? Thanks!